# trouble finding values of string read from file

Tags: ruby, arrays, string

I'm having trouble coming up with numerical values from strings for the following problem.
I have read from the file contained here http://projecteuler.net/project/words.txt and i successfully read it, but i don't know if my switch-case is working improperly or if i am having trouble with the array, i mainly program in c++ and am trying to learn ruby so my understanding of ruby syntax is still rudimentary at best

```
    #!/usr/bin/ruby -w

words = []
words = File::read("words.txt") 
parts = words.split(',')
puts parts
c=0
while parts != "YOUTH"
    a=0
    case parts
        when 'A'
            a+=1
        when 'B'
            a+=2
        when 'C'
            a+=3
        when 'D'
            a+=4
        when 'E'
            a+=5
        when 'F'
            a+=6
        when 'G'
            a+=7
        when 'H'
            a+=8
        when 'I'
            a+=9
        when 'J'
            a+=10
        when 'K'
            a+=11
        when 'L'
            a+=12
        when 'M'
            a+=13
        when 'N'
            a+=14
        when 'O'
            a+=15
        when 'P'
            a+=16
        when 'Q'
            a+=17
        when 'R'
            a+=18
        when 'S'
            a+=19
        when 'T'
            a+=20
        when 'U'
            a+=21
        when 'V'
            a+=22
        when 'W'
            a+=23
        when 'X'
            a+=24
        when 'Y'
            a+=25
        when 'Z'
            a+=26
    end
    b = false
    i = 1
    k= 0
    while b = false
        k += i  
        i += 1
        if a == k || i >15
            b == true
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Okay! so where is your problem?

Comment: i don't think that i am cycling through the array properly in my while loop but i don't know how to fix it in ruby

Comment: that's ok,but what's wrong you have seen in your code? what help you want from us? what does `words.txt` contain?

Comment: well i think it's the while parts !=  "youth" i don't know how to start at the first member of the array and go on in ruby, in c++ i would do for(int i = 0; parts[i] != 'YOUTH'; i++)

Comment: words.txt links to the file on prject euler that i posted a link to, basically i would like to know how to reformat in order to cycle thorugh my array properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Here is the official Doc`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-5B-5D)

Okay! so here is some hints to your problem:

```
"string".split(//)
#=> ["s", "t", "r", "i", "n", "g"]
"string".split(//).first
#=> "s"
"string".split(//).first(1)
#=> ["s"]
"string".split(//).first(3)
#=> ["s", "t", "r"]
```

some more way to do solve the problem:

```
"string".split(//)[0]
#=> "s"
"string".split(//)[1]
#=> "t"
"string".split(//)[0,4]
#=> ["s", "t", "r", "i"]
```

Comment: okay thank you, i'm sorry if my question seemed just a tad bit vague

Comment: no! its OK. did you get your confusion resolved? :)

Comment: @eldersouth what's the wrong with my tips? you unmarked it.

Comment: sorry, i'm new to stack overflow, i also upvoted another tip and i was not aware that it would unmark your tip

Comment: @eldersouth I think you can upvote each post when you would have 20 or 25 as rep :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the parts to a char array, along the lines of:

```
parts.split(//)
```

or

```
parts.chars.to_a
```

Then iterate over the char array.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what this code is suppossed to compute, but I've edited your code to make sense from a logical standpoint:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby -w

words = File::read("words.txt") ;
parts = words.delete('\"').split(',');
puts parts
c=0
while(c<parts.length)
    a=0
    each_word = parts[c].split('');
    for i in 0...each_word.length
        case each_word[i]
            when 'A'
                a+=1
            when 'B'
                a+=2
            when 'C'
                a+=3
            when 'D'
                a+=4
            when 'E'
                a+=5
            when 'F'
                a+=6
            when 'G'
                a+=7
            when 'H'
                a+=8
            when 'I'
                a+=9
            when 'J'
                a+=10
            when 'K'
                a+=11
            when 'L'
                a+=12
            when 'M'
                a+=13
            when 'N'
                a+=14
            when 'O'
                a+=15
            when 'P'
                a+=16
            when 'Q'
                a+=17
            when 'R'
                a+=18
            when 'S'
                a+=19
            when 'T'
                a+=20
            when 'U'
                a+=21
            when 'V'
                a+=22
            when 'W'
                a+=23
            when 'X'
                a+=24
            when 'Y'
                a+=25
            when 'Z'
                a+=26
        end
    end
    b = false
    i = 1
    k = 0
    while(b == false)
        k += i  
        i += 1
        if((a == k) || (i > 15))
            b = true
        end
    end
    c +=1;
end
```